# Run a self-hosted agent in Docker

Tags: azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am trying to run a self- hosted agent in docker, I have created the dockerfile and start.ps1 files and installed the Azure DevOps Server Express Admin console. I am getting a "Basic authentication requires a secure connection to the server " when I try running the container in docker ( switched windows containers) URL: http://computername/DefaultCollection

I have also attached a screenshot of the error

can you please advise how to resolve this issue.

[Docker Run error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzlFC.png)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Run a self-hosted agent in Docker

I could not reproduce this issue on my side with hosted agent windows-2019.

To test this issue, I created a folder `dockeragent` in my Azure repo, which including the files `Dockerfile` and `start.ps1`：

[image]

Then copy the content from the document [Run a self-hosted agent in Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops#create-and-build-the-dockerfile) to those two files.

Next, create a pipeline with an inline powershell task to create the docker image and run docker container:

```
cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\dockeragent

docker build -t dockeragent:latest .

docker run -e AZP_URL=https://dev.azure.com/<YourOrganizationName> -e AZP_TOKEN=<YourPAT> -e AZP_AGENT_NAME=mydockeragent dockeragent:latest
```

The test result:

[image]

To make it work, please make sure the file `Dockerfile` and `start.ps1` is correct without any change.

If above info not help you, please share the content of your `Dockerfile` and the steps you did.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am using Azure DevOps on Premises. So I have installed Azure DevOp Server 2019. URL: https://computername/DefaultCollection . I have followed your instructions above and got : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: Not sure if I need to setup the URL as HTTP or HTTPS . I am happy to reinstall it to make sure all settings are correct.

Comment: The (401) Unauthorized error means you do not have sufficient permissions, please confirm that your PAT has sufficient permissions.

Comment: I have Installed Azure DevOps on Premises with Http settings and ran the docker command. On step 3 (Configuring Azure Pipelines agent) I got an error " Basic authentication requires a secure connection to the server" I also check IIS and the Basic authentication is disabled. so not sure what to do now.

Comment: I also installed Azure DevOps on Premises with Https settings and ran the docker command. on step 1 ( Determining matching Azure Pipelines agent) I got an error " Invoke-RestMethod : The remote name could not be resolved: "ComputerName"                 At C:\azp\start.ps1:32 char 12  so not sure what to do here either. I also create new token for both scenarios which used in the docker run command.

Comment: Does  this solution is working for any one of you ?. I am also getting error saying Unable to find image 'dockeragent:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for dockeragent, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: I am able to see my agent online. But I have two problems here 1. Pipeline in which I am running docker image using PowerShell scripts runs infinitely 2. I am not able to use my agent to build my code

Answer (score 0):

Your are using azureDevOps without https.
Registering your PiplineAgent via PAT requires https (hence the error: "Basic authentication requires a secure connection to the server".

Try using other authentication Methoden (negotiation, which uses windows authentication)